# Is a p-value a sample statistic, or a population parameter, or neither?

Tags: p-value

I would also be interested to know why it is one or the other.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A p-value is a random variable, so it's not a population parameter.

You could certainly argue that it's a [statistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistic):

> A statistic (singular) is a single measure of some attribute of a sample (e.g., its arithmetic mean value). It is calculated by applying a function (statistical algorithm) to the values of the items of the sample, which are known together as a set of data.

A p-value appears to satisfy those conditions; a test statistic is a function of the data, and we apply a function to a test statistic to obtain a p-value (usually either a cdf, the complement of a cdf or sum based on both).

Comment: Could you argue that it isn't?

Comment: @Scortchi Someone might argue that it isn't usually thought of in those terms. I'd say that I wouldn't think of it as an estimator\*, but that it is a sample statistic. \*(at least not one I'd care to use for anything in general; in particular instances perhaps)

Comment: Actually, on reflection while strictly speaking any sample statistic could be called an estimator of any population quantity (though many are terrible for that purpose), I don't think it can be a reasonable estimator of anything useful. There's no "true p-value" that it converges to for example.

Answer (score 5):

A $p$-value is the probability of observing a test static value as or more extreme than the test statistic created from one's data *if the null hypothesis is true*. You can therefore interpret the $p$-value as a measure of how extreme your test statistic is under H$_{0}$ and the probability distribution attached to H$_{0}$. The $p$-value is therefore a statistic that is a function of one's data, and one's choice of H$_{0}$.

Answer (score 3):

If the test statistic can be called a statistic, then so must the $p$-value:  the test statistic is a function of the data under the assumption that the null hypothesis is true.  The $p$-value is simply a probability associated with that test statistic.